# Why is a float being converted to an int before adding?

Tags: c++11, gcc, x86

I was messing around on https://gcc.godbolt.org/ when I observed something peculiar. Consider the following function:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>

float dot(float src1[], float src2[], int size) {
  float* vecmul = static_cast<float*>(malloc(size * sizeof (float)));
  float dotprod = 0;
  std::transform(src1, src1+size, src2, vecmul, std::multiplies<float>());
  dotprod = std::accumulate(vecmul, vecmul+size, 0);
  free(vecmul);
  return dotprod;
}
```

With flags `-O3 -std=c++11` on `x86 gcc 4.9.2` this gets compiled down to:

```
dot(float*, float*, int):
// load args, do multiplication from std::transform (with mulss)
.L22:
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    addq    $4, %rcx
    cvtsi2ss    %edx, %xmm0 *
    addss   -4(%rcx), %xmm0 *
    cmpq    %rcx, %rsi      *
    cvttss2si   %xmm0, %edx *
    jne .L22              
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0    
    cvtsi2ss    %edx, %xmm0 
.L4:
// pop arguments, free, etc.
```

I'm curious as to why we have the float-to-int conversion, then an int addition, and then a conversion back (asterisked lines). Why would this be faster than a direct `fadd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::accumulate`'s accumulator's type is determined from its third argument. `0` is an `int`, so `std::accumulate(vecmul, vecmul+size, 0);` will convert the result of each intermediate addition to `int` and finally return an `int`.

You want `std::accumulate(vecmul, vecmul+size, 0.0f);` to make the accumulator a `float`.